# Executing <script src = "//website.com/?variables" > inside <div> retrieved by AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have this line of code that I am trying to run within an ajax loaded div:

```
    <noscript><p>Coupons powered by <a href="http://www.coupons.com/">Coupons.com</a></p></noscript>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//bcg.coupons.com/?scriptId=47051&bid=1293740001&format=718x940&bannerType=3"></script>
```

Here is a jsfiddle of some of my approaches:

http://jsfiddle.net/BF8K2/6/

I keep getting successful callbacks, but the content doesn't load into the divs

Thanks!

Comment: The code you have provided thus far should work just fine, assuming `//bcg.coupons.com/?scriptId=47051&bid=1293740001&format=718x940&bannerType=3` returns javascript that executes successfully.

Comment: The problem you are concerned about, is it that the injected script tag is not loading a file into the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate and insert your script element using `createElement`, `appendChild` and friends. Don't use `innerHTML` for this.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Quentin, I get successful callbacks with that approach, but the content doesn't load. See my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BF8K2/6/